# Comments appear in every post - Meteor

Tags: meteor

It has been two weeks and I still couldn't manage to make comments appear in the post they were written for. Every comment appears in every post. I'm near a nervous breakdown after trying lots of different tutorials, information or videos (basically everything google and meteor docs gave me) but I've been failing miserably...

Server:

```
Meteor.publish("posts", function () {
    return Posts.find();
});

Meteor.publish("comments", function() {
  return Comments.find();
});
```

Single-post.js

```
Template.singlePost.helpers({
    comments: function () {
      return Comments.find({},{sort: {createdAt: -1}});
    }     
});

Template.singlePost.events({
    "submit .new-comment": function (event) {
        var text = event.target.text.value;
        Meteor.call("addComment", text);
        event.target.text.value = "";
        return false;
    }
});
```

Inside Meteor.methods:

```
addComment: function (text) {
    if (! Meteor.userId()) {
        throw new Meteor.Error("not-authorized");
    }

Comments.insert({
  text: text,
  createdAt: new Date(),
  owner: Meteor.userId(),
  username: Meteor.user().username
});
},
```

And finally router:

```
Router.map(function(){
    this.route('top', {path:'/top'});
    this.route('trending', {path:'/trending'});
    this.route('new', {path:'/new'});
    this.route('singlePost', {path:'/post/:_id',
        data:function(){
            return Posts.findOne({_id:this.params._id})
        }
                             });
    })
```

I'm aware that I didn't include Comments in router or some other things about comments are missing because I tried countless different things and failed so I wanted to keep it clean for my future helper...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comments need to be joined to your posts via an id. So `addComment` should look something like:

```js
addComment: function (postId, text) {
  check(postId, String);
  check(text, String);

  if (!this.userId) {
    throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'not-authorized');
  }

  Comments.insert({
    text: text,
    createdAt: new Date(),
    owner: this.userId,
    username: Meteor.user().username,
    postId: postId
  });
}
```

Now all of your comments will be related to a post via `postId`. Then in your `comments` helper, you can join the two like this:

```js
comments: function () {
  selector = {postId: this._id};
  options = {sort: {createdAt: -1}};
  return Comments.find(selector, options);
}
```

And finally, your submit event:

```js
submit: function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var text = event.target.text.value;
  Meteor.call('addComment', this._id, text);
}
```

All of the above assumes the current context is a `post` document as indicated by the `data` hook in your router.

Comment: Dude... I f***ng love you! You didn't only solve my problem, but also taught me new thing I didn't know and I understood my previous mistakes as well. AWESOME!

Comment: Yeah as much as this answer works, that's great and all - but what about SUBSCRIPTION. The OP's code is subscribed to all data, which will kill your website on load.

Answer (score 0):

All comments are being shown because of this:

```
Template.singlePost.helpers({
  comments: function () {
    return Comments.find({},{sort: {createdAt: -1}});
  }
});
```

You're not passing the `find()` call any parameters to bring up comments for a certain post. For example:

```
Template.singlePost.helpers({
  comments: function () {
    return Comments.find({postId: ...},{sort: {createdAt: -1}});
  }
});
```

I'd need to see your full code to provide anything more helpful than this.